# VBA Formula - Adjustment per Row Data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
 Sub Sample()

     Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
     Dim ws As Worksheet

     Set ws = Sheets("Storage NSNR")

     lastRow = ws.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

     With ws
         For i = 1 To lastRow
             If Len(Trim(.Range("K" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then _
             .Range("L" & i).Formula = "=(NETWORKDAYS(J2, K2)-1)*($P$1-$O$1)+IF(NETWORKDAYS(K2,K2),MEDIAN(MOD(K2,1), $P$1,
 $O$1),$P$1)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(J2,J2)*MOD(J2,1), $P$1, $O$1)"
         Next i
     End With

 End Sub
```

Hi,

Can anyone help me on how can I adjust the formula:

`=(NETWORKDAYS(J2, K2)-1)*($P$1-$O$1)+IF(NETWORKDAYS(K2,K2),MEDIAN(MOD(K2,1), $P$1, $O$1),$P$1)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(J2,J2)*MOD(J2,1), $P$1, $O$1)`

I'm looking to automatically adjust "J2" and "K2" to "J3" and "K3" and so on, similar to dragging down the formula. I've looked everywhere but I can't seem to find the correct way of applying it.

Basically, the formula from the next column, "L1", until the last available entry for "K".

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Change to an xlR1C1 style formula and use .Range("L" & i).FormulaR1C1 =

Comment: Are you sure you want to use J2, K2 when your loop starts at row 1?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am currently studying R1C1 reference based from your suggestion. I am just new into VBA and usually rely on the record macro button and modify the codes that comes up.

Comment: See the ConvertFormula approach below. It still concerns me that your loop starts at L1 but the xlA1 formula references J2 and K2.

Comment: Sorry for that, the loop actually starts at L2, could this approach be also used in putting numbers 1-1000 for example beside each cell that has a value?

Comment: L2 makes much more sense! :) The `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Offset(0, 1)` can be used to identify typed numbers in the column then offset to another column and write numbers. There is also `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).Offset(0, 1)` for formulas returning numbers.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to an xlR1C1 style formula and use `.Range("L" & i).FormulaR1C1 = ...`

```
.Range("L" & i).Formular1c1 = "=(NETWORKDAYS(rc10, rc11)-1)*(r1c16-r1c15)+IF(NETWORKDAYS(rc11, rc11), MEDIAN(MOD(rc11, 1), r1c16, r1c15), r1c16)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(rc10, rc10)*MOD(rc10,1), r1c16, r1c15)"
```

If you are not too familiar with xlR1C1 syntax, let VBA do the work.

```
 Sub Sample()

     Dim i As Long, fA1 As String, fR1C1 As String

     fA1 = "=(NETWORKDAYS(J2, K2)-1)*($P$1-$O$1)+IF(NETWORKDAYS(K2,K2),MEDIAN(MOD(K2,1), $P$1, $O$1),$P$1)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(J2,J2)*MOD(J2,1), $P$1, $O$1)"
     fR1C1 = Application.ConvertFormula(Formula:=fA1, _
                                        FromReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
                                        ToReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, _
                                        RelativeTo:=Range("L2"))

     Debug.Print fR1C1
     '=(NETWORKDAYS(RC[-2], RC[-1])-1)*(R1C16-R1C15)+IF(NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],RC[-1]),MEDIAN(MOD(RC[-1],1), R1C16, R1C15),R1C16)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(RC[-2],RC[-2])*MOD(RC[-2],1), R1C16, R1C15)

     With Worksheets("Storage NSNR")
         With .Range(.Cells(2, "K"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp))
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = fR1C1
         End With
     End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It has been working perfectly. Will look into R1C1 further. Have a great day!